# AppResources.ResourceManager crashes with FileNotFound-Exception

Tags: maui, resourcedictionary

In an .NET MAUI App, I use AppResources.ResourceManager to translate resources from .resx-Files.

Already during Startup of my App in **Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)** Emulator I get a couple of FileNotFound-Exceptions:

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
    .UseSharpnadoTabs(loggerEnable: false)
    .UseSharpnadoCollectionView(loggerEnable: false)
    .UseLocalizationResourceManager(settings =>
    {
        settings.RestoreLatestCulture(true);

        // FileNotFoundException here
        settings.AddResource(AppResources.ResourceManager);
    })
    ...
```

**App.xaml**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          // FileNotFoundException here
        ...
    }
}
```

**LanguageResourceManager.cs**

```
public class LanguageResourceManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LanguageResourceManager()
    {
        AppResources.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    public static LanguageResourceManager Instance { get; } = new LanguageResourceManager();

    // FileNotFoundException here
    public object this[string resourceKey] => AppResources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey, AppResources.Culture) ?? Array.Empty<byte>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void SetCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        AppResources.Culture = culture;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
    }
}
```

**CalculatorViewModel.cs**

```
public partial class CalculateMacrosViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly LanguageResourceManager LanguageResourceManager;
    private static string AppTitle;


    public CalculateMacrosViewModel()
    {
        LanguageResourceManager = LanguageResourceManager.Instance;
        AppTitle = Translate("AppTitle");    // FileNotFoundException end here
    }

    private string Translate(string resourceString, object parameter = null)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            // FileNotFoundException here
            return $"{LanguageResourceManager[resourceString]}";
        }

        return string.Format(LanguageResourceManager[resourceString].ToString(), parameter);            
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my implementation or why do I have so many FileNotFound-Exceptions during startup of my app? Normally, I would say the resx-Dictionaries should already be integrated into the App and be available. Later on, I can work with the LanguageResourceManager without any problems, only during startup I get these Exceptions. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you really access the right resource in the project? You can check this [Retrieve a specific resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically#retrieve-a-specific-resource) for more information.

Comment: I am pretty sure, as I copy pasted all of them. I would also rather expect a KeynotFound Exception in such case. The first FileNotFound Exception occurs in  MauiProgram.cs already when it is registered. Strange Exception in my opinion

Comment: You can check the name of the .resx file, is the name as the same as AppResources.

Comment: Another way is that you can create another file and change the code then try to build the project again.

Comment: Naming is a good hint: actually, I have 2 files, one for the English and one for German resources. AppResource.resx and the other one AppResource-de.resx and that’s actually when the German one is loaded. How should I name this file for different languages?

Comment: Your file name is `AppResource` but you are using the AppResources. Here is the wrong code `settings.AddResource(AppResources.ResourceManager);` in your project. This is the reason why you can not get the file.

Comment: Have to correct what I wrote regarding the 2nd resx: it’s called „AppRespurce.de.resx“

Comment: I mean you should change the file name to match the name you are using in the code. You miss the "s" at the end of your file name.

Comment: Have to correct what I wrote regarding the 2nd resx: it’s called „AppRespurce.de.resx“. To be honest, I currently do not get it what you mean: `settings.AddResource(..)` allows to add a RespurceManager. Question is, where it gets its resource files, but they are Emedded resources and also later on, I get all my translations in all languages. What did you mean I am doing wrong in my Code?

Comment: Example from: https://github.com/SirJohnK/LocalizationResourceManager.Maui

Comment: when I change AppResource.ResourceManager it says „Cannot resolve symbol ‚AppResource‘“. My File name is obviously „AppResources.resx“ and „AppResources.de.resx“ - sorry for the confusion. Just looked it up on my PC 

Comment: Strangely enough, when I rename the German resx  to „AppResource_de.resx“ to access it in settings.AddResource(…) and add both, I can’t translate anymore. Whereas, when I have it with the old name „AppResources.de.resx“ and just add „AppResources.resx“ translation works as expected. Do you think changing the order in which I add .UseLocalizationResourceManager(…) to the builder could have a real impact on getting the FileMotFoundException or not? By the way, Build Action is „Embedded resource“

Comment: My resources are located in „\Resources\Localization\AppResources.resx“ and „\Resources\Localization\AppResources.de.resx“

Comment: This sounds like the order issue.

Comment: How do you think should I change it? Keep file names:  AppResources.resx and AppResources.de.resx or change? Do I have to change location so that these files are not in subfolder „Resources\Localization\..“? Or just put the AddResource(..) integration on MauiProgram.cs on top? Also is it enough to just add the „AppResources.ResourceManager“ and leave out the German one?

Comment: Changed the file names and tried also changing orders, same issue FileNotFound 

Comment: I checked the local sample and found that he just put the .resx file in the resource folder. You can check this [demo](https://github.com/SirJohnK/LocalizationResourceManager.Maui/tree/main/LocalizationResourceManager.Maui.Sample).

Comment: I tried it and moved the *.resx-Files just to subfolder "\Resources", still as embedded resource and one is called "AppResources.resx" the other one "AppResources.de.resx". Unfortunately, same exception on Startup. Could you run it successfully? When I look into the FileNotFoundException "ViewDetails", I can see a FileName called "MyApp.resources"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a remaining [issue](https://github.com/SirJohnK/LocalizationResourceManager.Maui/issues/4) on the package and the developer is trying to find the answer. You can follow it up for more information.

In addition, someone mentioned that it looks like be a MAUI bug which has a problem with [Fast Deployment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7443#issuecomment-1406701369).

You can try to disable the Android "Fast deployment" options setting for the sample project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Interesting comments also in the link to the package.